# Composer autoload files without running a command each time

Tags: php, composer-php

**This is a general question I have out of curiosity and might lead to something useful in projects of mine.**

Every time I add a new file (for example a new controller or model) I have to run `composer dump-autoload -o` for it to include the file, not sure if i'm just doing something wrong or if that is how it works.

Is it possible for me to get composer to see the file automatically after I created the file with its contents?

My first thought was to just create a script to run the command in either a special "refresh" file but that seems to be a waste.

I am using PSR-4 to load my files.

composer.json autoload:

```
    "autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "Website\\":"app"
    }
},
```

Comment: Maybe I read it wrong, but you want composer to pick up new files from your repository *without* telling composer to do it?

Comment: It would seem your composer autoload section is not properly configured. please paste it here so we can see. It is totally not the intended way, if you indeed apply psr-4 to your namespaces, follow a consistent file hierarchy and set composer properly, there is no command to run when adding new classes.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑno, not from my repo, just the local file system, i understand i would need to if i deploy it on another system.

Comment: [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/debug/debugging.html) handles this using their `app_dev.php` environment. I'm sure the other frameworks do as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your composer.json file so that the autoloader knows where to look for specific namespaces:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "src/"
  },
  "files": [
    "src/simpleFunctions.php"
  ]
}
```

After running `composer update`, the autoloader will know where to look when a script encounters a namespace that falls under these definitions automatically, without any further command to write.

---

You have to respect the file hierarchy and psr-4 while naming and creating your classes. In the example above, adding a `App\Controller\MyController` class is straightforward, you add it in the `Controller` folder and it will be autoloaded on your next run.

```
/src
  /Controller
    MyController.php
  /Model
    /Mappers
      MyMapper.php
  simpleFunctions.php
```

---

```
namespace App\Controller;
class MyController {}
```

**Casing is important!**

When seeing a namespace like `Website\Controllers`, the autoloader will look for there files, under the root for the namespace specified, with the same casing. That means, that if you are under a case sensitive system (like Linux distributions) you actually need to respect the case. In your case the class `Website\Controllers\Front` **must** be in `app/Website/Controllers/Front.php`.

Comment: See that's what i have (included my composer.json autoload at the top) but it doesn't do that.

Comment: You also must respect the file hierarchy and the namespaces. Website\Class MUST be in app/Class.php file.

Comment: i do i have that, i have my files in "/app/website/controllers "and each file has namespace "website/controllers". Would caps perhaps be a conflict?

Comment: yes indeed, the capital letters are important. some operating systems are case insensitive, but to be sure you'd have to respect the case. As you can see, in the file hierarchy in my examples, the folders have capital letters. it's not a coincidence.

Comment: i'll give it a try and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score -2):

Basically, Composer doesn't aware of files that you are creating, you have to run the `dump-autoload command` which won't download anything new. It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside your project.

Ideally, we execute composer dump-autoload -o , for a faster load of your webpages. The only reason it is not default, is because it takes a bit longer to generate (but is only slightly noticeable)

Comment: why negative please give reason

Comment: I am not trying to download a repo, but using composer to load all of the website files, which it does... just doesn't load in new files that i created for ex a new controller or model.